# laravel - why function call with no parentheses?

Tags: function, laravel, foreign-key-relationship, parentheses

I see this in a laravel tutorial :

```
Auth::user()->item;
```

where item is a function, inside models\User.php :

```
function item() { return $this->hasMany('Item', 'owner_id'); }
```

where Item is for models\Item.php

So why the parentheses is not needed when item function is called ?  Like : `Auth::user()->item();` 
If I put the parentheses, the browsers goes crazy and crash.

Also, if I rename Item.php to Item2.php, rename class Item to Item2, and I do `hasMany('Item2', 'owner_id')`, it won't work. But why ?  Where does 'Item' came from ?

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: Can you give us the context of `Auth::user()->item`? My preliminary conclusion is that somewhere needs the reference of the function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Laravel uses the magic function `__get` to handle arbitrary attributes.

This calls `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`'s `getAttribute` function, which checks the model's relations and returns the related item(s) if a relationship is present with that name.

The parentheses are not needed because `getAttribute` automatically executes the function `items()` when the attribute `items` is requested. You can, by the way, request `Auth::user()->item();` which will return a query builder you can work with.

Comment: But then, why this works :
Auth::user()->itemszo;

public function itemszo(){
          return $this->hasMany('Item', 'owner_id');
}

There's nothing 'itemszo' in my app.

Comment: @trogne When you request the attribute `itemszo`, it executes the function `itemszo()`, which **does** exist. That function creates a relationship with the `Item` model, which exists too.

Comment: Then, why if I do Auth::user()->getAuthPassword , without no final (), it won't execute the getAuthPassword() function ?

Comment: @trogne Because it's not coded that way. The `getAttribute` function looks for **relationships** specifically. The source for all this is freely available - https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2383 - so I suggest you look there for further answers.

Comment: Thank you ceejayoz! I know understand that while Laravel is looking for an attribute, it is also executing the function with the same name. This function is returning a big object of type "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany". By asking for the attribute, I get what hasMany is specifically meant for : a "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection" object.

Comment: I really hate all this Laravel magic; makes it hard to follow the flow of the code, and simply makes too many things implicit, and often just to save a couple keystrokes.. (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: @Rafa It's well documented, and a few keystrokes a bunch of times adds up. It's popular for a reason.

Comment: @ceejayoz sure, it is documented, that doesn't mean the framework shouldn't be as clear as possible. The programming language "Brainfck" is also documented... And code editors / IDEs already help with the extra typing. I haven't had to manually type a full for-loop in 17 years or more.. so why would saving a parenthesis be worth modifying the obvious behaviour an object's method call?

Comment: @Rafa It's quite clear, and saving a parenthesis isn't why this exists. `item` and `item()` in Laravel where `item` is a relationship do importantly different things.

Answer (score 2):

The method `item()` is setting up a relationship for the Eloquent ORM on how to prepare a query. calling `->item` is telling Eloquent through its [Dynamic Properties](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties) that you want Item and then Eloquent will use the method. You can only call the method directly if it is compatible with [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries). The example you give should work either way but there may be something I am missing.